# How to navigate to the next month when in the week view in react big calendar

Tags: react-big-calendar

i currently have the view prop in the calendar set to 'week'

```
function CalendarSchedule({eventList=[]}) {

const localizer =momentLocalizer(moment);

return (
        <Calendar
            localizer={localizer}
            view='week'
            events={eventList}
            startAccessor="start"
            endAccessor="end"
        />
       )
      }

export default CalendarSchedule;
```

the back and next buttons in the week view will show the next week when clicked

I want to have two extra buttons that can jump to the next or previous month when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `date` as a controlled prop, and a custom toolbar to add the additional buttons. The `onNavigate` is available in props, so you use this

```js
const navTwoWeeks = () => {
  const {date, onNavigate} = this.props;
  // do your date math to figure out new date
  onNavigate(navigate.DATE, newDate);
};
```